# Unable to find correct href using Selenium/BS4

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to ease my financial data collection using the below code. However, seems to have a couple of issues with it. I want to scrape the following page for a specific href: 'https://www.witan.com/investor-information/factsheets/#currentPage=1'

The href I am trying to parse:
href="/media/1767/witan-investment-trust_factsheet_310821.pdf"

Currently I am using selenium to do it, however it is a bit slow, so if it is possible to scrape using BS4 I am open for suggestions - my attempts so far have failed.

```
# Set options for selenium
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

# Requests website using Selenium & ChromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/AnaConda/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('https://www.witan.com/investor-information/factsheets/#currentPage=1') # Requests website
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
link_finder = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('/witan-investment-trust-factsheet'))[0]
```

When using the above code I get:
a class="ico-arrow document-view size" href="/media/1750/witan-investment-trust-factsheet-30jun2021.pdf" target="_blank"...

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML document with PDF links are loaded asynchronously via JavaScript (so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see them inside initial page). To print all PDF links, you can do:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://www.witan.com/umbraco/surface/listing/DocumentListing"

params = {
    "currentPage": "1",
    "year": "2021",
    "isArchive": "false",
    "pagination": "true",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    # load cookies:
    s.get("https://www.witan.com/investor-information/factsheets/")
    # get document page:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(api_url, params=params).content, "html.parser")
    for a in soup.select(".document-view"):
        print("https://www.witan.com" + a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.witan.com/media/1767/witan-investment-trust_factsheet_310821.pdf
https://www.witan.com/media/1763/witan-investment-trust_factsheet_310721.pdf
https://www.witan.com/media/1750/witan-investment-trust-factsheet-30jun2021.pdf
https://www.witan.com/media/1730/witan-investment-trust_factsheet_310521.pdf
https://www.witan.com/media/1718/witan-factsheet-30apr2021.pdf
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, it does not seem to be working anymore. This actually happens each month when they put a new document in, and can't seen to figure out why. Do you have any idea?